Tensorflow model response empty
I wrote a react native code that works properly. However, I cannot get the output I want as outputdata. I embedded my tflite extension model into the application. The outputData I get is as follows: {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
Below is the code I wrote:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { loadTensorflowModel } from 'react-native-fast-tflite';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'

const ClassPage = ({ route }) => {
    const { lang, img } = route.params;

    useEffect(() => {

        async function loadModel() {
            try{
                const model = await loadTensorflowModel(require('../../assets/image_classification_model.tflite'));
                console.log("model uploaded: ", model);

                const imageURI = img;
                const imageBlob = await RNFS.readFile(imageURI, 'ascii');
                const imageData = new Uint8Array(imageBlob.split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));

                console.log("necessary images: ",imageURI,imageData);
                
                const outputData = model.run([imageData]);
                console.log("Output data: ",outputData);
                
            }
            catch(error){
                console.error("Error occured! ",error);
            }
        };

        loadModel();
    }, []);



    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Image Classification</Text>
            <Text>Lang: {lang}</Text>
            <Image source={{ uri: img }} style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }} />
            
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
        header: {
            alignItems: 'center'
        },
    }
)

export default ClassPage;


I tried to change inputData format object to typearray but it didn't work either.

Looks like model.run([imageData]) is async function.
Call it with

const outputData = await model.run([imageData]);

